# Choosing minimum value and corresponding columns in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel Spreadsheet containing elements in 3 columns

```
Name Number Time
A      1   0.425
A      2   0.123
B      1   1.0256
B      2   0.564
B      3   0.7895
C      2   0.256
C      5   0.458
```

I want to choose minimum **Time** and corresponding **Name** and **Number**. I have tried it with pivot table and retrieved **Name** and minimum **Time** but could not get the corresponding **Number** column value.
EDIT :
Just to explain further. For each corresponding Name i want to choose minimum Time and then corresponding Number against that minimum Time. E.g. Output for above table should be like this :

```
Name Number Time
A    2      0.123
B    2      0.564
C    2      0.458
```

Comment: Is that a typo for Time in the `C` row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need three formulas

**Extract list of unique `Name`**

*This formula is an array formula so needs to be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while holding down <kbd>enter</kbd>*

```
E2: =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:$A$8),0)),"")
```

**minimum time for the Name**

```
G2: =AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(E2=$A$2:$A$8)*$C$2:$C$8,1)
```

**matching number for minimum time for name**

```
F2: =AGGREGATE(14,4,(E2=$A$2:$A$8)*(G2=$C$2:$C$8)*$B$2:$B$8,1)
```

The screenshot below should clarify where the formulas go and the referred ranges:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A2:C8, you can use the formula:

For Name:

```
=INDEX(A2:C8, MATCH(MIN(C2:C8), C2:C8, 0), 1)
```

For Number:

```
=INDEX(A2:C8, MATCH(MIN(C2:C8), C2:C8, 0), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I also want to choose the third column as well i.e. time. e.g.A 2 0.123

Comment: That's just `=min(C2:C8)` Which is in each of those formulas.

Answer (score 0):

A PivotTable can indeed do that for you:

[image]

This is accomplished by setting a Top 1 Values filter as follows:

[image]

[image]